# getOutputStream() has already been called for this response when fill data in child table with spring boot

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-rest

I am using spring boot 1.5.10 & spring rest to develop some rest services
I have relation one to many between product and services.

When I fill data in services table and access the service that get me all products(http://localhost:8080/user/products) give me this exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has
>   already been called for this response.

and repeated json appear in the browser!

If services table is empty: no exception is thrown. I don't know why.
I found [a link](https://gullele.com/spring-data-error-getoutputstream-already-called-response/) that discuss the problem but yet I couldn't solve it.

Product entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
public class Product implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "productId")
    private List<Service> servicesList;
}
```

Service Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "services")
public class Service implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "TYPE")
    private int type;

    @JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Product productId;
}
```

And the `ProductController`

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("user")
@CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:4200", allowedHeaders="*")
public class ProductController {

    @Autowired
    private IProductService productService;

    @GetMapping("product/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Product> getProductById(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
        Product product = productService.getProductById(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<Product>(product, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("products")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Product>> getAllProducts() {
        List<Product> list = productService.getAllProducts();
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Product>>(list, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

`pom.xml` is defined as follows.

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.app</groupId>
<artifactId>Assignment</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>Assignment</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the link you have shared, you need to create a response class to be sent to the client who is calling the API.

For example, you might have a class saying `ProductResponse` which might look like this.

```
public class ProductResponse implements Serializable {
    public Integer id;
    public String name;
    public List<Service> servicesList;
}
```

Now in the controller class, populate create the response as follows.

```
@GetMapping("product/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<ProductResponse> getProductById(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
    Product product = productService.getProductById(id);
    ProductResponse productResponse = createProductResponse(product);
    return new ResponseEntity<ProductResponse>(productResponse, HttpStatus.OK);
}

ProductResponse createProductResponse(Product product) {
    ProductResponse productResponse = new ProductResponse();
    productResponse.id = product.id;
    productResponse.name = product.name;
    productResponse.serviceList = product.serviceList; 
}
```

And yes, you need to specify the `FetchType.EAGER` in the entity class of `Product`.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
public class Product implements Serializable {

    // ... Other parameters

    @OneToMany(fetch = "FetchType.EAGER", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "productId")
    private List<Service> servicesList;
}
```

Hope that helps.